# bootstrap dropdown-menu no css format

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap dropdown menu, despite the right class being applied to the sublist, I'm losing my formatting and the padding that normally applies to bootstrap.

I'm using bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.2 as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[image: screenshot from dropdown-menu]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
        &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs navbar-collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img width="140" src="{% static 'images/openopps_logo.png' %}"</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'pricing' %}">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="{% url 'about' %}">
                    About
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}#vision">Vision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}#our_company">Our company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}#faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}#contact_us">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-oo-outline">Logout</button></a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'registration_register' %}"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-oo">Sign Up</button></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item oo-roboto-override"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'auth_login' %}"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-oo-outline">Login</button></a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you already tried an other version of bootstrap? Is there the same error?

Comment: It doesn't help your padding issue, but you are missing a `>` on line 6 for your image tag in your example above

Comment: Good shout. That works, but messes up everything else. I'll recheck the bs4 guidance.

Comment: You could also have a CSS constraint on li that's cascading over the bootstrap CSS... F12 in any browser will bring up the Developer Options, which will show you any CSS manipulation on any node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has an extra class required for dropdown menus. Using the following class in the `<li>` tags works.

```
<li class="dropdown-item"><a href="{% url 'about' %}#vision">Vision</a></li>
```

Comment: kind of strange that example from official documentation ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav ) doesn't work and this does